# How can I upside down and limitLine in charts in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios-charts

I made a android app and I'm making iOS app now.

I need a graph that upside down and has limit line.

In Android, I used MPAndroidChart.

In Xcode, I used Charts because it is almost same likes MPAndroidChart.

I have found I can use `isInverted` instead of `setInverted`

and ChartLimitLine instead of LimitLine.

This is codes what I wrote.

```
mChart.isInverted(axis: <#T##YAxis.AxisDependency#>)
mChart.ChartLimitLine(limit: 0.2, label: "")
```

I have no any idea that What is `YAxis.AxisDependency`.

And there is an error in limit line

> "alue of type 'ScatterChartView?' has no member 'ChartLimitLine'"

I an new in iOS, so I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to add the limit line in **XAxis** & **YAxis**.

**XAxis:**

```
let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
var limitLineX = ChartLimitLine()
limitLineX = ChartLimitLine(limit:5, label: "Limit Line average")
xAxis.addLimitLine(limitLineX)
```

**YAxis:**

```
let leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
var limitLine = ChartLimitLine()
limitLine = ChartLimitLine(limit:50, label: "Limit line average")
leftAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine)
```

For Invert property, it's still not supported on Charts iOS library. Maybe they will add soon to the newer version.

Hope this will helps!